# URL pathfinder in Django - any workaround when it keeps redirecting me to main view?

Tags: django, django-views

Sorry for being an embarrassing noob, but I have managed to complete like 99% of the Django Girls tutorial only to realize that there is one essential function in my basic blog site that's not working - the post titles on the main view don't link to their respective post views, even though the code seems alright to me... Guess I am really missing a glaringly obvious mistake! I was considering to switch from pk to slug, could that be an effective workaround?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <article class="post">
        <aside class="actions">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}">
              {% include './icons/pencil-fill.svg' %}
            </a>
            {% endif %}
        </aside>
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <time class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </time>
        {% endif %}
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

post_list.html

```
% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="post">
            <time class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </time>
            <h2><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: What do you mean by main view? Do you mean the view `post_list`? If so you should be showing the template for that view (`blog/post_list.html`) in your question.

Comment: edited post....

Comment: You write `<a href="">`. the `href` attribute is supposed to have the url you want to link to. In your case it should be `<a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Oh right, now it all works. Thank you very much! :)